# How to get notified in the calling activity when search dialog is closed?

Tags: android

I have an activity with a floating action button that triggers a search dialog. When the search dialog pops up, I am hiding the floating action button by overriding `onSearchRequested()`.

```
override fun onSearchRequested(): Boolean {
    fab.hide()
    return super.onSearchRequested()
}
```

When the dialog is closed, I want to show the fab again. The Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#LifeCycle say that I should be able to get notified when the dialog is closed by registering an `OnDismissListener` in the search dialog, but don't say how I can get a handle on the search dialog.

Comment: Pls, show your code.

Comment: @aiqency It's not really a debugging question. I posted the code where I hide the fab. I can posted the manifest code that sets up the search dialog, but I don't see how that would help.

Comment: You only need to get a reference to the instance of your DialogFragment. Did you use a DialogFragment or some kind of library?

Comment: Do you declare your search view and search manager in your code anywhere? That would be the code to post if any. This would allow a "search.setOnDismissListener(this);" Not sure of the Kotlin equivalent. Or as aiqency said, if the search is a separate fragment then listen for that to close or have a  callback when dismissing.

Comment: @C.Skjerdal No, I am following the android docs which say to declare my activity as searchable in the manifest like this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#SearchDialog. There is no reference to the search dialog in code.

Comment: @aiqency No, I am declaring my activity as searchable in the manifest. See my above comment.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog#ConfiguringWidget  - This should be where you declared it (same article but a bit lower)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity set a `OnDissmissListener` on `SearchManager`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.OnDismissListener

edit:

you can do it like this:

```
override fun onSearchRequested(): Boolean {
    val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager

    searchManager.setOnDismissListener {
        //dismiss code
    }

    return super.onSearchRequested()
}
```

Comment: But where do I get the SearchManager from? I have no reference to it.

Comment: Oh, I see SearchManager is a system service.